Failed to mount /home/user/Desktop/Share see systemctl status
I turn on the computer, and this is what I see. When I press Ctrl+D nothing happens, and going into root mode does not help. I need to make sure that this computer starts without problems.


You've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details; but my guess from the screenshot you provided (and lack of any other details) is a user made a change to the file-system table with mandatory requirements for that change, that couldn't be met - thus causing the failure to boot normally.  You've provided no specifics as to what you're running, nor what change(s) were made in the last session before this issue, or other details meaning we'd mostly be guessing at possible causes
